# perl binmode of utf-8 is only working with \x{codepoint} and not \x encoding for three byte encoding

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, utf-8

The [Euro character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) is 0xe282ac in UTF-8

I'm trying to use a string in perl with the UTF-8 character output to STDOUT.

So I set my script to be in UTF-8 with ['use utf8;'](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlunicode.html)

And I set up my STDOUT to be in UTF-8 with ['binmode'](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html).

An example script is:

```
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
print "I owe you 160\x{20ac}\n";
print "I owe you 80\xe2\x82\xac\n";  # UTF-8 encoding?
```

The \x{codepoint} works fine, but encoding the UTF-8 gives me an error:

```
I owe you 160€
I owe you 80â¬
```

Comment: The codepoint is *not* `0xe282ac` in UTF-8. That is purely how it's encoded as a bytestring.

Comment: Right - and can't I put that encoding in the string?  If not, how do I specify UTF-8 characters in strings?

Comment: In other words, doesn't "\x{e282ac}" insert those bytes into the string - and isn't that valid UTF-8?

Comment: See [`Encode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) for how to decode an UTF8 byte string into a Perl string

Comment: Try `print "\xe2\x82\xac"`. I believe the braced version specifies the codepoint, not an exact bytestring.

Comment: That gives me: "â¬"

Comment: `use utf-8` turns on utf-8 in the source, i.e. you can write `print "I owe you 160€\n"` (you need to save the script as UTF-8).

Comment: I know about putting utf-8 in the source.  And if I put the "€" in the source, it gets encoded as 0xe282ac, so perhaps I am not understanding how \x{} works in strings??

Comment: `\x{...}` specifies a Unicode codepoint, not a bytestring. The codepoint for the Euro symbol is [U+20AC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm).

Comment: Ah, finally managed to find the docs for \x in perl strings (Google doesn't do such a good job searching for things like '\x')  and you are right about \x{}...  but why isn't the \xe2\x82\xac working?

Comment: And editing the question with your info.

Comment: I suspect whatever you are using to read the output is decoding the output to an ANSI codepage, rather than decoding it as UTF-8. `\xe2\x82\xac` in the [ISO-8859-1 codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) is `â¬`.

Comment: If I redirect to a file, I can see that it's encoding the first Euro symbol as expected, 0xe282ac, but the second is becoming 0xc3a2c20x82c2ac, so somehow it's getting garbled, as if it's being encoded twice.

Comment: `"\x{20ac}"` produces a one-character string, while `"\xe2\x82\xac"` produces a three-character string. Of course they're not equivalent!!

Comment: @Phylogenesis, That's not the issue. Perl is printing U+000E2, U+00082 and U+000AC as requested. It has nothing to do with ANSI, code page or ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, Re "*I believe the braced version specifies the codepoint, not an exact bytestring.*", There is no difference between the braced version and the non-braced version. `"\xe2"` is 100% equivalent to `"\x{e2}"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a string that consists of the three bytes `E2 82 AC`, you can declare it like this:

```
my $bytes = "\xE2\x82\xAC";
```

The `\xXX` form in a double quoted string uses two hex digits (and always two) to represent one byte.

The string above contains 3 bytes.  If we pass the string to the `length` function it will return 3:

```
say 'Length of $bytes is: ' . length($bytes);    # 3
```

Perl has no way of knowing whether those three bytes are intended to represent the Euro symbol.  They could equally be a three byte sequence from inside a JPEG file, or a ZIP file, or an SSL-encoded TCP data stream traversing a network.  Perl doesn't know or care - it's just three bytes.

If you actually want a string of characters (rather than bytes) then you need to provide the character data in a way that allows Perl to use its internal representation of Unicode characters to store them in memory.  One way is to provide the non-ASCII characters in UTF8 form in the source code.  If you're doing this you'll need to say `use utf8` at the top of your script to tell the Perl interpreter to treat non-ASCII string literals as utf8:

```
use utf8;

my $euro_1 = "€";
```

Alternatively you can use the form \x{X...} with 1-5 hex characters representing the Unicode codepoint number.  This will declare an identical string:

```
my $euro_2 = "\x{20ac}";
```

Each of these strings contains a multi-byte representation of the euro character in Perl's internal encoding.  Perl knows the strings are character strings so the `length` function will return 1 (for 1 character) in each case:

```
say 'Length of $euro_1 is: ' . length($euro_1);    # 1
say 'Length of $euro_2 is: ' . length($euro_2);    # 1
```

The defining feature of Perl's internal representation of character strings is that it is for use *inside* Perl.  If you want to write the data out to a file or a socket, you'll need to encode the character string to a sequence of bytes:

```
use Encode qw(encode);

say encode('UTF-8', $euro_1);
```

It's also possible to use `binmode` or an argument to `open` to say that any string written to a particular filehandle should be encoded to a specific encoding.

```
binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)');

say $euro_1;
```

This will only work correctly for character strings.  If we took our original 3-byte string `$bytes` and used either `encode` or IO layers, we would end up with garbage, because Perl would take each byte and convert it to UTF8.  So `\xE2` would be output as `\xC3\xA2`, `\x82` would be output as `\xC2\x82` and so on.

However, we can use the `Encode::Decode` function to convert the 3-byte $bytes string into a single character string in Perl's internal character representation:

```
use Encode qw(decode);

my $bytes = "\xE2\x82\xAC";
my $euro_3 = decode($bytes);

say 'Length of $euro_3 is ' . length($euro_3);    # 1
```

One minor nitpick: In your original question you stated that `20AC` is *the* UTF-16 representation of the euro symbol.  In fact there are two different UTF-16 representations: UTF16BE and UTF16LE, with the latter using the opposite order: `AC20`.

Comment: All the answers are good, but this one helped me finally realize all that was happening here.  Hallelujah.

Answer (score 3):

As the [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) page that you link to described, the Unicode EURO SIGN character is at code point 20AC and may be referred to as `U+20AC`. In UTF-8 that is encoded as the three bytes 0xE2 0x82 0xAC

To add the Unicode character to a string, you may write

```
"I owe you \x{20ac}160\n"
```

or

```
"I owe you \N{EURO SIGN}160\n"
```

or

```
"I owe you \N{U+20AC}160\n"
```

or, if you `use utf8` at the top of your program, you may add the literal character with the same effect

```
"I owe you €160\n"
```

each of these will add a *single character* to the string with the required code point

If you use

```
"I owe you 80\xe2\x82\xac\n"
```

then you have created a string with three characters which correspond to the UTF-8-encoded EURO SIGN character, which is a very different thing. You may use `decode_utf8` from the [`Encode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) module to convert those bytes to a single character, but otherwise you have a UTF-8-encoded string, which is a different thing from a character string

Here's an example program

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;

use Encode qw/ decode_utf8 :fallbacks /;

for my $s (
        "I owe you \x{20ac}160\n",
        "I owe you \N{EURO SIGN}160\n",
        "I owe you \N{U+20AC}160\n",
        do { use utf8; "I owe you €160\n" },
        decode_utf8(my $ss = "I owe you \xe2\x82\xac160\n") ) {

    print $s;
}
```

#### output

```
I owe you €160
I owe you €160
I owe you €160
I owe you €160
I owe you €160
```

Note that there is no need for `use utf8` unless you are using non-ASCII characters in the source code, such as `€`. You may access characters by their Unicode names (which are always in ASCII) as shown above

> If I redirect to a file, I can see that it's encoding the first Euro symbol as expected, 0xe282ac, but the second is becoming 0xc3a2c20x82c2ac, so somehow it's getting garbled, as if it's being encoded twice.

It *is* being encoded twice. You encode the character yourself the first time by supplying the UTF-8-encoding "\xe2\x82\xac" for the character, and the `binmode` on your output file handle encodes each of those characters a second time, giving `C3 A2` for `E2`, `C2 82` for `82` and `C2 AC` for `AC`

Answer (score 3):

You are building two different strings, so getting different results shouldn't be surprising.

You are performing what is called "double-encoding". You had a string that was already encoded using UTF-8, and you asked Perl (using `binmode` and `print`)  to encode it a second time. That was a bug on your part.

---

The string literal `"\x{20ac}"` produces a one-character string (`0x20ac`).

```
$ perl -E'say length("\x{20ac}")'
1
```

When you print it to a handle with the `:utf8` handle, you are instructing Perl to treat those characters as Unicode Code Points and encode them using UTF-8.

As requested, Perl prints the following encoded using UTF-8:
U+020AC EURO SIGN (€).

```
$ perl -E'binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; print "\x{20ac}"' | od -t x1
0000000 e2 82 ac
0000003

$ perl -E'binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; say "\x{20ac}"'
€
```

---

The string literal `"\xe2\x82\xac"` produces a three-character string (`0xe2, 0x82, 0xac`).

```
$ perl -E'say length("\xe2\x82\xac")'
3
```

(`"\xe2\x82\xac"` is the same thing as `"\x{e2}\x{82}\x{ac}"`.)

When you print it to a handle with the `:utf8` handle, you are instructing Perl to treat those characters as Unicode Code Points and encode them using UTF-8.

As requested, Perl prints the following encoded using UTF-8:
U+000E2 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX (â),
U+00082 BREAK PERMITTED HERE and
U+000AC NOT SIGN (¬).

```
$ perl -E'binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; print "\xe2\x82\xac"' | od -t x1
0000000 c3 a2 c2 82 c2 ac
0000006

$ perl -E'binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; say "\xe2\x82\xac"'
â�¬
```